# I am trying to store random data into a second array

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to store randomly generated data into a second array so that I am able to press a button to go back to it. At the moment I press back and there is nothing there. I think it is due to the items not being correctly stored in the second array. I will provide the code for reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var randomGeneratedQuotes = Array <String>()
var currentlyShown : String?
var randomQuote: String {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
    return myQuotes[randomNumber]

}

var previousRandom: String? {

    if currentlyShown == randomQuote {
        let previous = randomGeneratedQuotes.index(of: currentlyShown!)! - 1
        return randomGeneratedQuotes[previous]
    }

    return randomGeneratedQuotes.last
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var randomQuote: String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
        return myQuotes[randomNumber]

    }

    func storePrevious() {
        if randomGeneratedQuotes.contains(randomQuote) {return}
        randomGeneratedQuotes.append(randomQuote)
    }

    quotesLabel.text = randomQuote


}

//right hand button tapped

@IBAction func RHSButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var randomQuote: String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
        return myQuotes[randomNumber]


    }

    func storePrevious() {
        if randomGeneratedQuotes.contains(randomQuote) {return}
        randomGeneratedQuotes.append(randomQuote)
    }
    quotesLabel.text = randomQuote


}

//left hand button tapped

@IBAction func LHSButton(_ sender: Any) {


    func pressedBack() {
        currentlyShown = previousRandom


    }

    quotesLabel.text = previousRandom
}
```

Comment: Please format your code at the top (`var randomGeneratedQuotes = Array ()`)

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a specific question? It currently looks as though you're asking us to debug a huge blob of code.

Comment: sorry. basically, I am randomly generating a number in an array that corresponds to a quote that is then displayed on a label. I would like to know how I can get the last randomly generated quote/number to be appended to a new array?